# changing bundle id of released app while releasing a new version

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store

i am developed an ios app and its released on the market. now I want to upgrade it. what would happen if I change the bundle id of the app and release it. 

 will it make it a separate app??

 or if not will it still auto upgrade for customers who have already installed it?
pls help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you change the bundleID it will be release as an new app.

Thus existing user will not receive it as an update.

Comment: i released a new version but changed the bundle id. so now users are not getting updates. if u re-release it with the same bundle id as before will it make things ok?

Comment: Yes, the budleID is what identifies your app, thus changing it will create a new app.

Comment: so u mean, re-updating the app with the old bundle id will make things fine for ppl who have already installed the app?

Comment: First off you can not update an app when you changed the bundleID, since this would have created a new app. Thus you can only update an app which has the same BundleID as the previous one.